Spring boot application not working inside docker container: error on postgres db connection
I am new to Docker, I am trying  run my spring boot app on a docker container
The app relies on Postgres DB, which it is running on my local.
Those are the step I've done
application.properties
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TechDB
spring.datasource.username= myuser
spring.datasource.password= mypass

Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:22
LABEL maintainer="myself"
ADD target/AppToTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar AppToTest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "AppToTest.jar"]

Create the image:
docker build -t apptotest:latest .

run the container
docker run -p 8000:8080 apptotest

When I try to call my API on port 8000 I get server error on spring side:
[nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001  
[nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Just to clarify, the app works fine when I run simple spring boot app, and the it retrieves Data from my Postgres properly
                     ***Edit***

I've tried to run both postgres container and db altogether with composer file, with following steps:
I added to DockerFIle:
FROM postgres:15.1-alpine
COPY *.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

I created schema init script in the project folder.
I created docker-compose.yml file
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "apptotest"
    container_name: "my-postgres"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "newdb"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
      PGDATA: "/data/newdb"
    volumes:
       - newdb:/data/newdb
    ports:
       - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
   volumes:
     newdb:
       external: true

then I build images for both postgres and myapp, then I run the containers in this way, first I run postgres container and then my app:
docker network create test_network
docker volume create newdb
docker-compose up -d  

at this point I see my DB instance has started correctly, then I try to run my app container with this command:
docker run --name apptotest--network test_network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password" -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres:5432/newdb -p 8000:8080 apptotest

When I run the command I see no errors, but I can't see Spring boot application running, and I cannot contact API I created if I fire them on postman.
On the logs I see only DB related information
 LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-09-17 09:17:37 UTC
 LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections


It doesn't look like that you have postgres in your container. So when your app try to connect to localhost it can't, because no one listens.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

You have to think what localhost would imply in a docker container context.
It would imply that the Postgres is running inside the container along the webapp, which it doesn't, as it runs on your system.
In order to access it you have multiple options, I will give you the simplest solution which involves just running simple docker commands.
Docker commands
Run both as docker containers in the same network:
docker network create my_custom_network
docker run --name my-postgres --network my_custom_network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres
docker run --name my-app --network my_custom_network -p 8000:8080 apptotest

And that would change your property to
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres:5432/TechDB

You can also give the spring datasource property as an environment variable
docker run --name my-app --network my_custom_network -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres:5432/TechDB -p 8000:8080 

Keep in mind that you need to recreate the DB structure every time you destroy the container.
In order to prevent this, you can create a volume that can store that Postgres data:
docker volume create postgres-data

You should also create an SQL initialization script that you can pass to the Postgres container.
This will change your initial Postgres run command to something like this:
docker run --name my-postgres --network my_custom_network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password -d -p 5432:5432 postgres -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -v /postgresql/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

For a more in depth solution I would recommend setting up a docker compose file so you don't need repeat the commands above.
If you still want to have Postgres deployed directly on your system you can start your application with:
docker run --name my-app --network host -p 8000:8080 apptotest

Or if you are on windows or on mac you can give host.docker.internal instead of localhost. This works as long as you use the bridge network (which should be the default one if you don't specify anything else)
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/TechDB

Docker compose
Bellow you can find a sample configuration for docker compose.
services:
  app:
    image: apptotest
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: my-postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres_password
      POSTGRES_DB: TechDB
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:


I have created volume and docker compose file, do you know how can I run postgres container with docker compose?

I added edit to my original question, I tried to run with docker compose, but still I am not able to contact API in my app

Updated my answer to also include a docker compose file.
